# C# assembly.load from a byte[] issues

Tags: c#, .net, assembly.load

I have an EXE loaded into a byte array, and I am trying to load it into an assembly object using Assembly.Load.  I am getting errors trying to load.

Here is the code that is causing the exception:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load(bin);
```

bin is my byte array, loaded from the EXE.

**Here is the exception I am getting:**

> Could not load file or assembly '109590 bytes loaded from calc_tester, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the file you're trying to load is a .NET Managed exe/dll.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but because it is an EXE, it might be failing because of the unmanaged headers in the EXE?

Why not just do a LoadFrom( filename )?